# Usage of product name on commercial website

Tags: copyright, trademark

I have a software application that backups up customer data to their respective Google Cloud or Onedrive or Sharepoint.
If I mention this feature on my application's website, will I have to take permission from Google or Microsoft ?

Comment: I see that you've listed your location on your profile as Mumbai, so I'm assuming that is the jurisdiction the website is in. (Is it?) Also, are you asking this question from a standpoint of whether you would be breaking the law, or whether you would be breaking the terms of service? In any case, I'm not a lawyer but my gut feeling here is that as long as you clarify on your website e.g. that Onedrive and Sharepoint are Microsoft trademarks, a simple mention of an application feature shouldn't be against the law in most places.

Comment: You are right I am from Mumbai (Maharashtra) so laws of this place will apply ? Yes I can make a clear mention that Onedrive and Sharepoint are Microsoft Trademarks. Thank You.

Comment: [Fair Use in US Trademark Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fair_use_(U.S._trademark_law))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The large corporations such as those you've mentioned have certain **guidelines** when it comes to usage of their **brand names** (and **logos**).

If you search for "corporation name" + copyright permission you should get some relevant links. In the case of Microsoft for example: [Microsoft Trademark and Brand Guidelines](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/legal/intellectualproperty/trademarks)

Abbreviated for demonstration purposes but that page should answer all your questions:

> #### Do’s
>
> In general, you may do the following with Microsoft’s wordmarks and names of software, products, or services:
>
> - Note if your product or service is compatible or interoperable with a Microsoft product or service.
>
>   - Contoso software works with Microsoft OneDrive.
>   - Contoso headphones are compatible with Microsoft Surface devices.
>   - Contoso Software for Microsoft Azure
>   - Contoso is a new device designed for Microsoft Teams Rooms.
> - Truthfully and accurately refer to Microsoft and its products and services.
>
>   - Contoso is a three-dimensional model city created by students using Minecraft gaming software.
>
>   ...
>
> Include a trademark footnote to give notice that you are using Microsoft’s trademarks, e.g., “Microsoft, (list additional trademarks
> in alphabetical order) are trademarks of the Microsoft group of
> companies.”
>
> ...

But that can depend on the type of **relationship** you have with those service providers (if any). If you are an approved **reseller** of some kind, then different guidelines may apply and you may enjoy some more privileges. For example you may be eligible to display a gold partner badge or permitted to advertise your brand more prominently along your partner's.

Another useful and related link: [Use of Microsoft copyrighted content](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/legal/intellectualproperty/copyright/permissions)